# How to use the Probabilistic Occupancy Map framework

Tags: algorithm, opencv, computer-vision

Can somebody teach me how to use [Probabilistic Occupancy Map framework](http://cvlab.epfl.ch/software/pom) ?
I tried so hard, but I cant

---

edit:

thank you @Mr E that help me
i have 3 camera and the homography matrix is:

```
camera 1:
-0.211332  |   -0.405226    |    70.781223

-0.019746  |    -1.564936   |     226.377280

-0.000025  |    -0.001961    |    0.160791

camera 2:

0.000745    |   0.350335     |    -98.376103

-0.164871   |   -0.390422     |   54.081423

0.000021    |   -0.001668    |    0.111075

camera 3:

0.089976   |    1.066795     |    -152.055667

-0.116343   |   0.861342      |   -75.122116

0.000015   |    0.001442      |   -0.064065
```

and in config file:

```
ROOM 360 288 3 ?
RECTANGLE <camera number> <location number> notvisible|<xmin> <ymin> <xmax> <ymax>
```

in user manual said: Defines the parameters of a certain rectangle, standing for an individual at a certain location viewed from a certain camera. All non-specified rectangles are "not visible" by default.

in test.pom "configuration file" the number of locations is 1330 
how can i generate rectangles parameters?

Comment: Please can you post the code for your attempt at using the framework?

Comment: i just want to import my sequence to framework and get result , i record my sequence and calibrated them and i have all homography parameters , but i cant use them in framework,can you tell me how to defined rectangles parameters in config file

Comment: @reza_razavi As it stands your question is too broad... Spend a little time dong an [edit] on your post explaining how you've got to the point you're at and ask a *specific* question (rectangles parameters) and you might get an answer...

Comment: @reza_razavi I don't think you will get an answer without showing how your parameters are currently defined in your code. Otherwise an answer is just guesswork. The same goes for your past questions. Look at some OpenCV questions that have good answers and you will probably see some code in the question.

Comment: @Mr E thank you, but i search a lot to find out but nothing out there, i think the software require plane ground grid pixels but couldn't find anything

Comment: You can check here;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477120/how-to-configure-probabilistic-occupancy-map-people-detector?rq=1